# API requests(Mantis BT) from another domain - preflight error

Tags: rest, api, coldfusion, mantis

I'm developing a Mantis BT client in ColdFusion but I have a problem when I try to make requests from a different domain.

If I making requests from the same domain where I installed Mantis BT all work fine but when I try to make a request from a different domain or the same domain with another port(localhost:8500 - ColdFusion) the browser return "Failed to load https://localhost/mantis/api/rest/users/me: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401." error.

I have added all headers in mantis config but it still not working.
If I try to make a request with postman all work fine.

```
var settings = { 
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true, 
  "url": "localhost:8080/mantis/api/rest/users/me", 
  "method": "GET", 
  "headers": { 
      'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
      'Authorization': 'MAzzT5UD4cjxwwOayyLFAXnlIPQJmiL_'
      }
  } 

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) { console.log(response); });
```

Comment: Do you have any code that generates this?

Comment: The code request is: var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/mantis/api/rest/users/me",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'MAzzT5UD4cjxwwOayyLFAXnlIPQJmiL_'
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});  I have already added headers in mantis config [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701216/how-to-make-http-request-to-mantisbts-rest-api-using-angular-http)

Comment: Looks like you have a stray ; on the line with the url

Comment: I wrote it accidentally when I replaced your comment :D

Comment: Is it now correct?

Comment: No, it doesn't work yet. As I say if I make a request from the same domain where I installed mantis it work but if I make a request from another domain or the same domain with different port browser return a preflight error in console.

Comment: Whav version of ColdFusion are you running? Can you get a really rest example to work? Like a text file with JSON or something?

Comment: I resolved it by enable headers module in apache. Thanks

Comment: You should write that up as answer so that others can benefit from what you have learned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by enable headers module in apache.